# How to debug "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError"?

Tags: android, service, binding

This code is working in Android Lollipop, Marshmallow & Oreo. But it not in Kitkat.

When I call below code in Application Class.

```
m_MainService_Interface = new MainService_Interface(getApplicationContext());
```

My code

```
public MainService_Interface(Context context) {

        mServiceConnection = new ServiceConnection() {
            @Override
            public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {
                m_MainService = ((MainService.MainServiceBinder) service).getService();
            }

            @Override
            public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
                mServiceConnection = null;
                m_MainService = null;
            }
        };

        context.bindService(new Intent(context, MainService.class)
                .setPackage(context.getPackageName()), mServiceConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
    }
```

An error occurs in `mServiceConnection = new ServiceConnection`.

```
    @Override
        public void onCreate() {

            super.onCreate();
            m_MyApplication = this;
            m_MainService_Interface = new MainService_Interface(getApplicationContext());
    }

MainService_Interface class

public MainService_Interface(Context context) {

        mServiceConnection = new ServiceConnection() {
            @Override
            public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {
                m_MainService = ((MainService.MainServiceBinder) service).getService();
            }

            @Override
            public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
                mServiceConnection = null;
                m_MainService = null;
            }
        };

        context.bindService(new Intent(context, MainService.class)
                .setPackage(context.getPackageName()), mServiceConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
    }
```

Comment: Post your error logs here.

Comment: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.ep.universe.service.MainService_Interface$1

Comment: Post all code with calling and full of your class.

Comment: Also tell if you are using pro-guard in your app.

Comment: What's your minimum sdk?

Comment: minSdkVersion 19 targetSdkVersion 26

Comment: @Khemraj yes i using pro-guard ..

Comment: Post your `proguard-rules.pro` file, and show your error logs.

Comment: `-dontwarn android.support.v4.**
-dontshrink`